# Align text support

Tags: alignment, center

I am looking to apply a buy bottom to a column in field 3 of a table on this page.

http://hamabeadpatterns.co.uk/hama-beads/midi-beads-5/disney-gift-sets/

However when I do so, how can i get the buttom to align in the dead center of the field.  As apposed to the bottom center?

Comment: The center of the table? You could add padding to the bottom and top of the element.

Comment: Tables are for...tables, not layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: middle;` to your `<td>` tag.

Comment: Ive done <td style="text-align:top-center;vertical-align:middle;">  it puts it middle but not centre?